# AFrame light change not working

Tags: aframe

Running

`document.querySelector("[light]").components.light.data.color="#A00";`

Doesn't do anything, it will add `color="#A00"` if flushToDOM as an attribute but not change the light.

Changing `light="color:#BBB"` does work by hand, but what is the best way programmatically to do this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the `data` object directly isn't supported - you'll want to use `setAttribute` instead. Example:

```
var lightEl = document.querySelector('[light]');
lightEl.setAttribute('light', {color: '#a00'});
```

Comment: Oh gosh! Perfect, I had tried `light.setAttribute("color","#a00")` or `setAttribute("light.color"..` Thank you!

Comment: Ah you were close! Another option that works is `light.setAttribute('light', 'color', '#a00')`.